# how to sort NSArray and access in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

Below is the web API `response` I am storing in `**NSArray**`. How can I access in `**NSString**` based on index path?

Below is preview of image banner :

```
array(
    (
    "abc.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc1.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc21.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc2.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc3.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc4.jpg"
),
    (
    "abc5.jpg"
))
```

Comment: can you show me demo string? which string you want?

Comment: NSString *logo = [[dataarray objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"logo"];

Comment: I don't have any key's for the above particular Array

Comment: Objective-C basics 1 - Don't use the white space to define a variable.

Comment: want to make string from whole array or only selected indexpaths only?

Comment: You seem to have an array of arrays.  So `array[index][0]` will give you the string.  If you need to know which index has a particular string, that's a different story.

Comment: I need to Access all the images

Comment: you need string like "abc.jpg,abc1.jpg,abc2.jpg"? right

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
NSString *logo = [[dataarray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I need to access all the Images

Comment: Welcome and Enjoy ...!!

Comment: can anyone show me whats the wrong in the given answer who have down vot to this answer?

Answer (score -1):

for one image in string

```
NSString *strImage = YourimageArray[index][0]
```

for multiple images in one string

```
NSMutableArray *mutArrImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i< YourimageArray.count; i++) {
        [mutArrImages addObject:YourimageArray[i][0]];
    }

    NSString *strImages = [mutArrImages componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```